# What will happen if I upload a large file in larger chunks i.e. greater then 1024 bytes?

Tags: java, android, http, design-patterns

So I have got a large file **~20MB** that has to be uploaded to web-server and I am following the approach below :

- Read the file from storage `input stream`
- Create a `byte buffer` of size **1024**
- Create an `output stream` and write `byte buffer` to it
- Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the file is completely read and written

Now , I have a few questions,

1. To upload a large file like this I have to repeat steps 2 and 3 for `20 * 1024` times. What if I want to reduce the number of iterations i.e. by increasing the `byte buffer` size to **4096** and hence the number of iterations `20 * 256`. What could be the ramifications of this apart from **outofmemory** on android ?
2. Are there any changes required on the **web-server** if I modify this size based upon the size of cache that I would create on android at **runtime**(it may vary from device to device) ?
3. I also need to resume the upload if it is broken in-between due to network or server issues and for that matter I have thought of keeping the last block number that was successfully sent and thereby sending the next block when internet is available or server responds. Is this the right approach ? Is there anything already available or I am trying to reinvent the wheel here ?
4. Is there any order in which these blocks or byte arrays send to server are received ?

Comment: Increase the buffer to 100K and see what happens. You can easily investigate buffer size on upload speed yourself. Why ask us?

Comment: won't 100k result into `outofmemory` ?

Comment: Again: try and find out. This are all easy tests you can do yourself.

Comment: This is not the only doubt that I have but one of others !'

Comment: Add 2. No you don't have to change the webserver. Add 3. That is not possible. You will not get in between messages from a http server about received blocks. You can send as much blocks as you want and they will be accepted by the os but maybe not reach the server. You only know that all is received if you are finished and go read response. Add 4. Yes TCP/IP guarantees that.

Comment: I came to know that if I increase the size of buffer then I will be consuming more bandwidth from server and there would be a network congestion and if 1000s of users upload the file at the same time then there would be a lot of traffic towards the server . Is it right ? and is it the reason for using 1024 ?

Comment: That all is nonsense. Moreover why would you bother? Who uses 1024 these days?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62953/discussion-between-prateek-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Using a buffer size of 1024 is quite small.  The TCP layer will try to push full packets across the network.  Full packets are usually 1.5K bytes unless jumbo frames are involved.  Thus if you write 1K to a network socket, the TCP packet won't necessarily get pushed out until you write the next 1K.  This is to minimize the amount of overhead per data byte sent.
2. Most enterprise-grade web servers can easily handle POST requests in the 10's of megabytes in size if not larger.  I come across this in my job often.
3. This has been done already - sorry I don't have any pointers off the top of my head.
4. HTTP goes over a stream-oriented protocol like TCP, so bytes are received in the same order as they are received.  There is no notion of a 'block' in TCP - you send a stream of bytes, and the receiver gets a stream of (in order) bytes.

Comment: top answer - nothing left to say!